Vue3 props/slots reactivity
I wrote a "tree" component in vue3, with some slots to data-display customization.
It works well, but some days ago I found a problem. The case is:
I need an input into a slot of a a tree-node, and the v-model of the input is the field displayed into the same node.
I was expecting the value in the node to be automatically updated with the value of the input (because of reactivity), but this is not happening and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.
The value in my model is correctly updated, because if i force-update the tree (with a :key), the valued shown in the tree-node updates as expected.
Here is some code.
tree.vue (my main component)
// tree.vue
<template>
    <div :class="wrapperClasses">
        <tree-node v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"
                :item="item"
                :level="0"
                :first-child="index == 0"
                :last-child="index == items.length - 1"
                :key-accessor="keyAccessor"
                :text-accessor="textAccessor"
                :children-accessor="childrenAccessor"
                :is-leaf-fn="isLeafFn"
                :node-classes-fn="nodeClassesFn"
                @icon-click="(item, data, event) => $emit('icon-click', item, data, event)"
                @item-collapsed="(item, data) => $emit('item-collapsed', item, data)"
                @item-expanded="(item, data) => $emit('item-expanded', item, data)"
                @node-mounted="(item, data) => $emit('node-mounted', item, data)"
                >
            <template v-for="(slotName, idx) in Object.keys($slots)"
                    :key="`${index}-${idx}`"
                    v-slot:[slotName]="slotData"
                    >
                <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="slotData"></slot>
            </template>
        </tree-node>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TreeNode from './tree-node.vue';

export default {
    name: 'pn-tree',
    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            default: [],
        },
        keyAccessor: {
            type: [String, Function],
            default: 'key',
        },
        textAccessor: {
            type: [String, Function],
            default: 'value',
        },
        childrenAccessor: {
            type: [String, Function],
            default: 'children',
        },
        isLeafFn: {
            type: Function,
            default: (item, vm) => !vm.childrenList.length,
        },
        nodeClassesFn: {
            type: Function,
            default: (item, vm) => '',
        },
    },
    computed: {
        wrapperClasses(){
            return {
                'pn-tree': true,
                'root': true,
            };
        },
    },
    components: {
        TreeNode,
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
// not relevant :: omitted
</style>

tree-node.vue (recursive component for data display)
<template>
    <div :class="wrapperClasses" :key="key">

        <div class="icon"
                @click="onIconClick"
                >
            <slot name="icon" v-bind="slotData">
                <pn-icon
                        :lr-icon="isLeaf ? 'simple-circle' : (collapsed ? 'angle-right' : 'angle-down')"
                        ></pn-icon>
            </slot>
        </div>

        <div class="text">
            <slot name="text" v-bind="slotData">
                {{ text }}
            </slot>
        </div>
        
        <div class="right-slot">
            <slot name="right-slot" v-bind="slotData"></slot>
        </div>

        <div class="children">
            <tree-node v-for="(child, index) in childrenList" :key="index"
                    :item="child"
                    :level="level + 1"
                    :last-child="index == childrenList.length - 1"
                    :key-accessor="keyAccessor"
                    :text-accessor="textAccessor"
                    :children-accessor="childrenAccessor"
                    :is-leaf-fn="isLeafFn"
                    :node-classes-fn="nodeClassesFn"
                    @icon-click="(item, data, event) => $emit('icon-click', item, data, event)"
                    @item-collapsed="(item, data) => $emit('item-collapsed', item, data)"
                    @item-expanded="(item, data) => $emit('item-expanded', item, data)"
                    @node-mounted="(item, data) => $emit('node-mounted', item, data)"
                    >
                <template v-for="(slotName, index) in Object.keys($slots)"
                        :key="index"
                        v-slot:[slotName]="slotData"
                        >
                    <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="slotData"></slot>
                </template>
            </tree-node>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import { PnIcon } from 'xxx';


let TreeNode = {
    name: 'pn-tree-node',
    props: {
        item: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
        keyAccessor: {
            type: [String, Function],
            default: 'key',
        },
        textAccessor: {
            type: [String, Function],
            default: 'value',
        },
        childrenAccessor: {
            type: [String, Function],
            default: 'children',
        },

        level : {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
        firstChild: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        lastChild: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        isLeafFn: {
            type: Function,
            default: (item, vm) => !vm.childrenList.length,
        },
        nodeClassesFn: {
            type: Function,
            default: (item, vm) => '',
        },
    },
    data(){
        return {
            collapsed: false,
            loading: false,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        wrapperClasses(){
            return {
                'node': true,
                [`level-${this.level}`]: true,
                'loading': this.loading,
                'collapsed': this.collapsed,
                'expanded': !this.collapsed,
                'single-root-node': this.singleRootNode,
                'first-child': this.firstChild,
                'last-child': this.lastChild,
                'leaf': this.isLeaf,
                ...this.nodeClassesObj,
            };
        },

        singleRootNode(){
            return this.level == 0 && this.firstChild && this.lastChild;
        },

        key(){
            return (typeof this.keyAccessor == 'function' ? this.keyAccessor(this.item) : this.item[this.keyAccessor]) || '';
        },
        text(){
            return (typeof this.textAccessor == 'function' ? this.textAccessor(this.item) : this.item[this.textAccessor]) || '';
        },
        childrenList(){
            return (typeof this.childrenAccessor == 'function' ? this.childrenAccessor(this.item) : this.item[this.childrenAccessor]) || [];
        },
        isLeaf(){
            return this.isLeafFn(this.item, this);
        },
        nodeClassesObj(){
            let nodeClasses = this.nodeClassesFn(this.item, this);
            if (!nodeClasses) {
                return {};
            }
            if (typeof nodeClasses == 'string') {
                return {
                    [nodeClasses]: true,
                };
            }
            if (Array.isArray(nodeClasses)) {
                return nodeClasses
                        .reduce((a, x) => {
                            a[x] = true;
                            return a;
                        }, {})
                        ;
            }
            return nodeClasses;
        },

        slotData(){
            return {
                item: this.item,
                component: this,
            };
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onIconClick(event){
            this.$emit('icon-click', this.item, this.slotData, event);
            if (!this.isLeaf) {
                this.setCollapsed(!this.collapsed);
            }
        },
        
        setLoading(loading) {
            this.loading = !!loading;
        },
        setCollapsed(collapsed) {
            this.collapsed = !!collapsed;
            this.$emit(this.collapsed ? 'item-collapsed' : 'item-expanded', this.item, this.slotData);
        },
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$emit('node-mounted', this.item, this.slotData);
    },
};

TreeNode.components = {
    PnIcon,
    
    // TreeNode: () => import('./tree-node.vue'),
    TreeNode: defineAsyncComponent(() => Promise.resolve(TreeNode)),
}

export default TreeNode;
</script>

<style lang="scss">
// not relevant :: omitted
</style>

tree-tester.vue (just a test for my tree.vue component...just add @input="refresher++" into the input to force refresh)
<template>
    <div>
        <pn-tree
            :key="refresher"
            :items="rootItems"
            key-accessor="code"
            text-accessor="description"
            :children-accessor="getChildrenList"

            @icon-click="onIconClick"
            @item-collapsed="onItemCollapsed"
            @item-expanded="onItemExpanded"
            @node-mounted="onNodeMounted"
            >
        <template #right-slot="{ item }">
            <input
                    v-model="item.description"
                    ></input>
        </template>
    </pn-tree>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { PnTree } from './tree.vue';

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            refresher: 0,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        geographicDataList(){
            return [{
                code: 'CND',
                description: 'Canada',
            },{
                code: 'USA',
                description: 'USA',
            },{
                code: 'AL',
                description: 'Alabama',
                parentCode: 'USA',
            },{
                code: 'AK',
                description: 'Alaska',
                parentCode: 'USA',
            }]
        },
        rootItems(){
            return (this.geographicDataList || [])
                    .filter(x => !x.parentCode)
                    ;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        getChildrenList(item){
            return (this.geographicDataList || [])
                    .filter(x => x.parentCode == item.code)
                    ;
        },

        onIconClick(item, data, event) {
            console.log('onIconClick', item, data, event);
        },
        onItemCollapsed(item, data) {
            console.log('onItemCollapsed', item, data);
        },
        onItemExpanded(item, data) {
            console.log('onItemExpanded', item, data);
        },
        onNodeMounted(item, data) {
            console.log('onNodeMounted', item, data);
            data.component.setCollapsed(item.code != 'USA');
        },
    },
    mounted(){
    },
    watch: {
        geographicDataList: {
            deep: true,
            handler() {
                console.log('watch geographicDataList', this.geographicDataList);
            },
        },
    },
    components: {
        PnTree,
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.pn-tree {
    width: 450px;
}
</style>

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Its not really a vue3 project, try to  use ref and reactive to improve it first.

Well I'm pretty sure it's an actual vue3 component ("vue": "^3.4.21" taken from pagkage.json of the project I am using it in)...just using options api instead of composition (because this component was originally written for vue2 and I am currently migrating).
Can you please give me more detail about what you mean with "improve". I already tried reactive, but maybe not in the correct way
